# Ember this.set in component

Tags: ember.js, render, init, ember-components

I seem to be doing something wrong with the `init` property of an Ember component.

My code looks something like this.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('initial_value', this.get('value'));
  },

  change(e){
    console.log('value should be reset to ' + this.get('initial_value')) //This prints the initial value correctly.
    this.set('value', this.get('initial_value')); // this line does not update value.
    //this.set('value', 'hello'); //this line does update value.   
  }
});
```

Why can I update `value` with a string literal but not with `this.get('initial_value')`?

And I tried this code, swapping out `init` for every function in the lifecycle of a component.  I did this because I thought it had some to do with the rendering; kind of still do.

Here is the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8e5f4b68f0c271cb159c12fe5b8b8dee?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).

Comment: I find the twiddle a bit confusing: what's with all that `dup` code...is that relevant? Who is calling `change`? I tried making `change` an action and adding a button to call it, and using an `{{input...` helper for proper two-way binding of `value`...but then uncommenting the `hello` line had no effect either.

Comment: I guess I did not update the twiddle. I needed to change names and change some of the actual code I am working with to create the twiddle.  Hopefully it should be updated. Basically I need to set a variable in the `change` function to a value of a variable that was set in `init`.

Comment: still cannot reproduce the problem. If I add `this.set('value','something else');` to the init method (otherwise the value is `'initial value'` for the whole twiddle anyway), then entering, typing into an then leaving the input field results in it being reset to `'initial value'` as intended (or `'hello'` if the respective line is uncommented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just include `{{input value=value}}` in my-component.hbs file, when you change the input it will call `change` function in input helper which will call `change` function of your component which will reset it to `initial_value`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used, `<input type="text" value={{value}}>`, its one-way binding. i.e., on changing `value` in the component the change will get reflected in the input box, but changing the value in the input box will not change the value of the variable `value` in the component.

In Ember, DOM gets updated only when the value of the variable in the component changes. In `my-component.js`, the value of variable `value` is not changing. It just contains the string literal `initial value`.

For instance, `this.set('value', Math.random());` this will work as the value of the variable `value` changes.

> *Why can I update value with a string literal but not with this.get('initial_value')?*
>
> It can be done only once as the value changes only 1 time. (While changing the value to string during first time)

**To achieve your case**,
You can use `{{input value=value}}` which implements two-way binding. When editing your input box, the value of the variable `value` changes.

On focussing out, `this.set('value',this.get('initial_value'))` will set the initial value as required.

[Twiddle for reference](https://ember-twiddle.com/b21e2ae675bcb42b0a95eaee6c72d6c4?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)